# Chrome-extension: How to send message from content.js to popup.js - Page_Action

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Chrome v64.

**I want to send a message from content.js to popup.js.**

I managed to send a message from popup.js to content.js. But how to do it the opposite way? I have also downloaded a sample extensions, which also don't work.

Do I have to add a special permission?
I tried one time messaging and long running message channel.

**Permissions:**

```
 "permissions": [
    "background",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "webRequest",
```

**Content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    data: "mauzen"
}, function (response) {
   return true;
});
debugger;
var port = chrome.runtime.connect({
    name: "knockknock"
});
port.postMessage({
    joke: "Knock knock"
});
port.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
    debugger;
    if (msg.question == "Who's there?")
        port.postMessage({
            answer: "Madame"
        });
    else if (msg.question == "Madame who?")
        port.postMessage({
            answer: "Madame... Bovary"
        });
});
```

**Background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    sendResponse({
        data: "background"
    });
    if (request.data === "success") {
        alert("success");
    } else {
        //alert(request.data);
    }
});

console.assert(port.name == "knockknock");
port.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
    if (msg.joke == "Knock knock")
        port.postMessage({
            question: "Who's there?"
        });
    else if (msg.answer == "Madame")
        port.postMessage({
            question: "Madame who?"
        });
    else {
        port.postMessage({
            question: "background"
        });
    }
});
```

**Popup.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
    sendResponse({
        data: "popup"
    });
    if (message.data === "success") {
        alert("success");
    } else {
        // alert(message.data);
    }
});

chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {
    console.assert(port.name == "knockknock");
    port.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
        if (msg.joke == "Knock knock")
            port.postMessage({
                question: "Who's there?"
            });
        else if (msg.answer == "Madame")
            port.postMessage({
                question: "Madame who?"
            });
        else {
            port.postMessage({
                question: "popup"
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what I found out, testing around a bit.

To send a message **from the content.js** script to your popup you do the following:

```
 chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
                    data: "Hello popup, how are you"
                }, function (response) {
                    console.dir(response);
                });
```

and **in your popup.js**:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
    sendResponse({
        data: "I am fine, thank you. How is life in the background?"
    }); 
});
```

##### The message sent from content.js to popup.js will only be received, when your Popup is active (=open)

, i.e. you click on your page_action (browser_action) icon in the toolbar and the popup appears, then it is open/active. And only then, it can send and receive messages!

**Example popup:**
[image]

---

**You can test it like this**

Put the following script in you **content.js:**

```
 var timer = 0;
  var si = setInterval(() => {
            try {
               chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
                    data: "Hello popup, how are you"
                }, function (response) {
                    console.dir(response);
                });
                timer++;
                if (timer === 5) {
                    clearInterval(si);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                // debugger;
                console.log(error);
            }
        }, 2000);
```

**and in your **popup.js**:**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
    alert("I am popup!");
    sendResponse({
        data: "I am fine, thank you. How is life in the background?"
    }); 
});
```

As long as the `setInterval` executes you can click on your extension icon, to open the popup, then it will show an alert.

Comment: I have used your code but I get this error `Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.`

Comment: I get that too unless you have the popup open first. And no amounts of `try catch` do anything to prevent this.

Comment: Does anyone know if calling `chrome.action.openPopup();` (Firefox, mv3) counts as "opening"/activating the popup for sending messages ?  Have an extension use case that would need to display/open the popup and pass message it without the user directly opening it. I wasn't able to get this working by calling `chrome.action.openPopup();` before the `sendMessage()` code.

Answer (score 0):

From your code it looks like you are sending a message from your content script to the background and popup script, as opposite to what you described.

Sending a message from your extension to content script requires you to use `chrome.tabs.sendMessage`, see https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging

Comment: `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` is to send messages **TO** content scripts, not FROM them.